# Knockout.js bound input value not updated when I use jquery .val('xyz')

Tags: knockout.js

I have an input that has a knockout binding to the value.

When I update the value using jquery's .val() method, the changed value is not reflected in the viewModel.

I need to use jQuery to set this value.  How can I trigger the update to the viewModel?

Answer (score 146, accepted):

`.val()` does not trigger the change event.  So, you can just do .`val("blah").change()` for KO to pick up the changes.

Comment: What if you don't have control on that `val()`? Is there a way for jQuery to listen to `val()` on elements?

Comment: But really letting knockout do all the dom manipulation is a better approach, imho.

Comment: Make sure you check you `data-bind` statement too.  I had this bug before I realized it should be `data-bind="value:location"` and *NOT* `data-bind="value:location()"`