# Knockoutjs updating multiple observables in one calculation

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to do a calculation with Knockoutjs that seems to work, but I also want to output some variables to the html.

In the code below I'm calculating `viewModel.LooptijdOnafhankelijkeBedragen`, 
but I also want to output

1. noMonths
2. ((noMonths/36) * bedragarray[0].DP)
3. (36-noMonths)
4. (((36-noMonths)/36) * bedragarray[0].EP )

that are calculated in `ko.computed`. What would be the best way to do this without having to do the calculation more than once?

```
//*** Looptijd Onafhankelijke Bedragen ***
viewModel.LooptijdOnafhankelijkeBedragen    =
    [
        {startdatum: new Date(2013,7,1),einddatum: new Date(2013,12,31),EP: 1029,DP: 1235,EO: 2281,DO:2735},
        {startdatum: new Date(2014,1,1),einddatum: new Date(2014,12,31),EP: 1044,DP: 1244,EO: 2244,DO:2744},
        {startdatum: new Date(2015,1,1),einddatum: new Date(2015,12,31),EP: 1055,DP: 1255,EO: 2355,DO:2755},
        {startdatum: new Date(2016,1,1),einddatum: new Date(2016,12,31),EP: 1066,DP: 1266,EO: 2366,DO:2766},
        {startdatum: new Date(2017,1,1),einddatum: new Date(2017,12,31),EP: 1077,DP: 1277,EO: 2377,DO:2777}
    ];



viewModel.LooptijdOnafhankelijkBedrag = ko.computed(function() {
   var looptijdOnafhankelijkBedrag = 0;
   if(viewModel.HoofdzaakStartDatum() != 'undefined') //TODO better check
   {
   var bedragarray = $.grep(viewModel.LooptijdOnafhankelijkeBedragen, function (el) {
            return el.startdatum <= viewModel.HoofdzaakStartDatum() &&
                    el.einddatum > viewModel.HoofdzaakStartDatum()
             });
        if(bedragarray.length == 1)
        {
            switch(viewModel.TypeZaak())
            {
                case "1": //Enkele zaak particulier
                    return bedragarray[0].EP;
                break;
                case "2": //Enkele zaak ondernemer
                    return bedragarray[0].EO;
                break
                case "3": //Enkele zaak particulier ontbonden
                    if(viewModel.OntbindingDatum() != 'undefined') //TODO better check
                    {
                        var noMonths =  MonthDiffIncluding(viewModel.HoofdzaakStartDatum(), viewModel.OntbindingDatum() );
                        if(noMonths>0)
                        {
                            if(noMonths > 36)
                            {
                                //max = 36 months
                                noMonths = 36;
                            }

                            //Evenredig deel enkel en dubbel afhankelijk van datum onbinding
                            return ((noMonths/36) * bedragarray[0].DP) + (((36-noMonths)/36) * bedragarray[0].EP );
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return 0;
                        }
                    }
                    return 0;
                break;
                case "4": //Enkele zaak ondernemer ontbonden
                        if(viewModel.OntbindingDatum() != 'undefined') //TODO better check
                    {
                        var noMonths =  MonthDiffIncluding(viewModel.HoofdzaakStartDatum(), viewModel.OntbindingDatum() );
                        if(noMonths>0)
                        {
                            if(noMonths > 36)
                            {
                                //max = 36 months
                                noMonths = 36;
                            }
                            //Evenredig deel enkel en dubbel afhankelijk van datum onbinding
                            return ((noMonths/36) * bedragarray[0].DO) + (((36-noMonths)/36) * bedragarray[0].EO );
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return 0;
                        }
                    }
                    return 0;
                break;
                case "5": //Dubbele zaak particulier
                    looptijdOnafhankelijkBedrag = bedragarray[0].DP;
                break;
                case "6": //Dubbele zaak ondernemer
                    looptijdOnafhankelijkBedrag = bedragarray[0].DO;
                break;


            }
        }

   }
   return looptijdOnafhankelijkBedrag;
   }).extend({currency: 2});


//calculates the difference in months between 2 dates
//Including the startmonth and EndMonth
function MonthDiffIncluding(startDate, endDate) {
    var months = 0;
    try
    {
    if(startDate != 'undefined' && endDate != 'undefined') //TODO better check
        {
            months = (endDate.getFullYear() - startDate.getFullYear()) * 12;
            months -= startDate.getMonth();
            months += endDate.getMonth() + 1;
         }
    }
    catch(ex)
    {
        months  = 0;
    }
    return months <= 0 ? 0 : months;
}
```

Thanks Peter

Comment: Please set up a working example of your code on jsFiddle and include a more thorough explanation of what `LooptijdOnafhankelijkBedrag()` is supposed to calculate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already found out myself: I could change the value of an observable with jQuery:`$("#LOBAantalMaandenVoorOntbinding").val(noMonths).change();`
see also [Knockout.js bound input value not updated when I use jquery .val('xyz')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018885/knockout-js-bound-input-value-not-updated-when-i-use-jquery-valxyz)

Comment: If you're still interested, I've made a fiddle with some improvements to your code but got distracted before I could turn it into an actual answer. I don't want to throw it away silently and you might get some ideas from it. http://jsfiddle.net/SjhHr/

Answer (score 0):

Without having fully understood your code (which a) seems overly complicated and b) is missing definitions for some of the observables you use), the general answer is:

You create observables (computed ones, in this case) for them.

Any observable caches its value, so if you use it repeatedly throughout your code it won't be re-calculated every time. If fact observables are only calculated once: when they are created (and after that only when one of their dependencies changes).