# Make knockout listen to values changes which are not a result of a keystroke

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

```
self.totalHours = ko.pureComputed(function() {
        var start=self.num1;
        var end=self.num2;
        return start+end; 
});

<input   type="text" data-bind="textInput: start">
<input  type="text" data-bind="textInput: end">
<input  type="text" data-bind='text: totalHours()'>
```

The above first is part of my `viewmodel` and the second is part of my `model`. num1,num2 are **observables**. Every time I change **manually** the value inside the above first two inputs the third input is updated immediately; however, when the values change **by code**, knockout does not listen to the changes and `total` is not updated. How may I oblige knockout to listen to the changes provoked by code?

Comment: How are you changing the values by code, give an example. If you are just accessing the model and changing the value there... it wont budge, knockout reforms the object on `applyBinding` and uses it's own structure.

Comment: Possibly this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018885/knockout-js-bound-input-value-not-updated-when-i-use-jquery-valxyz

Comment: Thanks Roy J. That solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

Quite some stuff you can fix and improve here:

- A computed value will re-evaluate when an observable it uses in its method changes: `self.num1` and/or `self.num2` need to be observable *and* evaluated using `()`
- If you want to bind an `<input>`'s value, you have to use either the `value` or `textInput` data-bind; the `text` bind will **not** work.
- If you want to write to a computed, you'll have to specify a `write` method. You'll have to tell knockout how to update the computed's dependencies to make sure all values add up. (e.g.: setting `totalHours` could set `num1` to `totalHours` and `num2` to `0`)
- You've bound to `start` and `end`, while your viewmodel properties are named `num1` and `num2`.
- When using `value` or `textInput`, user input will be returned as a string. You'll need to parse the strings to numbers if you want to use them in any math.

Now that all code should be working correctly, you can update your viewmodel's values via the inputs, or via code:

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  
  self.num1 = ko.observable(0);
  self.num2 = ko.observable(0);
  
  self.totalHours = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    var start = parseFloat(self.num1());
    var end = parseFloat(self.num2());
    return start + end;
  });
  
};

var vm = new ViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(vm);

// Updating your values from code:
vm.num1(1);
vm.num2(2);

// Whenever the values need to be updated via js,
// you should change the source values, _not_ the
// <input>'s values. Worst case scenario, you'll
// have to do something like this:

var updateNum1ViaDOM = function() {
  ko.dataFor(document.querySelector("input")).num1(5);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-bind="textInput: num1">
<input type="text" data-bind="textInput: num2">
<span data-bind='text: totalHours'></span>
```

---

*Note*: it's probably better to use an extender to force `num1` and `num2` to be numeric: [Live Example 1: Forcing input to be numeric](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html)

Comment: However, you say nothing about my question! In case num1 or num2 are changed by code, the text inside the span will not be updated automatically. It is updated only if I change the values manually...

Comment: When you fix the errors, there should be no differences between updating an observable from code (e.g.: `self.num1(12)`) or via the input fields. When you want to change the values, you should change the viewmodel properties, not change the DOM elements' attributes. How are you "changing the values by code"?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is a copy paste problem but the the code you posted will not work as intended. I've updated the example, when changing an observable value it must be passed as parameter so as not to overwrite the knockout observable

```
self.start = ko.observable();
self.end = ko.observable();

self.totalHours = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.start() + self.end();
});

<input   type="text" data-bind="textInput: start">
<input  type="text" data-bind="textInput: end">
<input  type="text" data-bind='text: totalHours()'>

//Then when changing the value by code
var newValue = 42;
model.start(newValue); //assuming you are making the change outside your viewmodel
```

*Just noticed this code will throw an exception when you edit the input bound to totalHours as it does not have a write handler defined. This is a separate issue though.