# KnockoutJS doesn't bind fields that have been autocompleted

Tags: c#, knockout.js

I'm using an external file where I get company data. The autocomplete works just fine, inputs get filled. But when I save the page into my database all the autocompleted fields don't get bind.

```
 public Save(saveorder: Boolean): void {
    let order: Order = ko.toJS(OrderPage.Instance().Order);
    let date = OrderPage.Instance().Order.DateAccepted;
    let removefromorderlines: Array<number> = [];
    OrderPage.Instance().j$.each(order.OrderLines, (index: number, orderline: OrderLine) => {
        // Check if there are any orderlines that don't have a modelid 
        if (orderline.ArticleModelId == null) {
            removefromorderlines.push(index);
        } 
    });
    let previousindex: any = 0;
    $.each(removefromorderlines, (index: number, orderlineindex: number) => {
        order.OrderLines.splice(orderlineindex - previousindex, 1);
        previousindex++;
    });
    if (saveorder == true) {
        OrderPage.Instance().ToggleDisableButton('btnSaveOrder', true);
        webApi.Execute(HttpRequestType.Post, '/Order/SaveOrder', order, OrderPage.Instance().OnSaveSuccess, OrderPage.Instance().OnSaveError);
    }
```

The data that is missing is inside of 'Order'. The data gets picked up as soon as I change anything about the inputs. I've tried to use "valueUpdate: 'input'" but no success so far.

This is my autocomplete code:

```
namespace Services {



interface kvkResult {
    handelsnaam: string;
    dossiernummer: number;
    straat: string;
    huisnummer: number;
    huisnummertoevoeging: string;
    postcode: string;
    plaats: string;
    ModelId: string;
    displayname: string;
    ContactPersonModelId: string;
}

interface Contact {
    ModelId: string;
    displayname: string;
}

export class kvkFactory
{
    private ctlCompanyName: string;
    private ctlContainerName: string;
    private ctlCoc: string;
    private ctlAddress: string;
    private ctlAddressNumber: string;
    private ctlAddressNumberSuffix: string;
    private ctlZipCode: string;
    private ctlTown: string;
    private ctlModelId: string;
    private ctlContactPersonModelId: string;

    /** Function to Fetch data from kvk api
    @ctlSearch: Input control for coc organisations 
    @ctlAutocompleteContainer: output control to display organisations result.
    @ctlCocClass: output text control for Kamer voor koophandel nummer
    @ctlAddressClass: output text control for address organisation
    @ctlZipCodeClass: output text contorl for zip code organisation
    @ctlTownClass: output text contorl for town of settlement organisation
    */
    constructor(ctlSearch: string, ctlAutocompleteContainer: string, ctlCompanyNameElement: string, ctlCocElement: string, ctlAddressElement: string, ctlAddressNumberElement: string, ctlAddressNumberSuffixElement: string, ctlZipCodeElement: string, ctlTownElement: string, ctlModelIdElement?: string, ctlContactPersonModelIdElement?: string, webapiurlforsearch?: string)
    {
        this.ctlCompanyName = ctlSearch;
        this.ctlContainerName = ctlAutocompleteContainer;
        this.ctlCompanyName = ctlCompanyNameElement;
        this.ctlCoc = ctlCocElement;
        this.ctlAddress = ctlAddressElement;
        this.ctlAddressNumber = ctlAddressNumberElement;
        this.ctlAddressNumberSuffix = ctlAddressNumberSuffixElement;
        this.ctlZipCode = ctlZipCodeElement;
        this.ctlTown = ctlTownElement;
        this.ctlModelId = ctlModelIdElement;
        this.ctlContactPersonModelId = ctlContactPersonModelIdElement;

        $(this.ctlCompanyName).keyup(function () {
            clearTimeout(this.typingTimer);
             this.typingTimer = setTimeout(() => { kvkfactory.searchKvk(webapiurlforsearch); }, this.doneTypingInterval);
        });
    }

    typingTimer: number;
    datafound = (data: any): void =>
    {
        let resultobject: ResultObject<kvkResult> = data;
        let companies = resultobject.Records;


        $(kvkfactory.ctlContainerName).empty();
        $(kvkfactory.ctlContainerName).show();
        $(kvkfactory.ctlContainerName).append('<table>');
        $.each(companies, function (i, item) {
            let entry: kvkResult = item;
            $('table', kvkfactory.ctlContainerName).append("<tr class=\"auto-complete-item\" data-modelid=\"" + entry.ModelId + "  \" data-contactpersonmodelid=\"" + entry.ContactPersonModelId +"  \"data-id=\"" + i + "\"><td>" + entry.handelsnaam + "</td><td>" + entry.straat + " " + entry.huisnummer + "</td><td>" + entry.postcode + "</td><td>" + entry.plaats + "</td></tr>");

        });
        $(kvkfactory.ctlContainerName).append('</table>');
        $(".auto-complete-item").on("click", function () {
            let id: string = $(this).data("id");
            let contactidnumber = 1;
            let contactid: string = $(this).data('contactidnumber');
            let modelid: string = $(this).data("modelid");
            let contacts = companies[contactidnumber];
            let organisationmodelid: string[] = null;
            let count: number = 0;   
            let company: kvkResult = companies[id];
            if (kvkfactory.ctlModelId != undefined && modelid!=null ) {
                $(kvkfactory.ctlModelId).val(modelid);
                $(kvkfactory.ctlContactPersonModelId).val(organisationmodelid); 
                                                                      }
            $(kvkfactory.ctlCompanyName).val(company.handelsnaam);
            $(kvkfactory.ctlCoc).val(company.dossiernummer);
            $(kvkfactory.ctlAddress).val(company.straat);
            $(kvkfactory.ctlAddressNumber).val(company.huisnummer);
            $(kvkfactory.ctlAddressNumberSuffix).val(company.huisnummertoevoeging);
            $(kvkfactory.ctlZipCode).val(company.postcode);
            $(kvkfactory.ctlTown).val(company.plaats);
            $(kvkfactory.ctlModelId).val(company.ModelId);
            $(".auto-complete-container").hide();
            Materialize.updateTextFields();
        });

        $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
            let container = $(".auto-complete-container");

            if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
                && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
            {
                container.hide();
            }
        });
    };
    doneTypingInterval: number = 800;
    searchKvk = (webapiurlforsearch?: string): void => {
        if ($(this.ctlCompanyName).val().length >= 3) {
            if (webapiurlforsearch == undefined) {
                webapiurlforsearch = variables.websiteurl + "/Kvk/Getdata";
            }
            let val = $(this.ctlCompanyName).val();
            webApi.Execute(HttpRequestType.Get, webapiurlforsearch, { name: val }, this.datafound, null);
        } else {
            $(".auto-complete-container").empty();
        }
    }
}
```

}
let kvkfactory: Services.kvkFactory;

Comment: How have you implemented autocomplete? With a plugin? Via a `<datalist>`?

Comment: Through a simple class name. The autocomplete looks for the input names inside my html and replaces the values with the data from the autocomplete.

Comment: If you change an `input`'s value through code, without using knockout, you'll need to make sure knockout is updated. Knockout requires you to use a custom binding  if you want to include custom input logic. If you share your autocomplete code I can show you how

Comment: Ah, Stackoverflow didn't notify me of your comment. The autocomplete code is held inside an external file, away from the KO code.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7019607/3297291) explains how you can fix your issue. (After `.val`, trigger a `.change` to allow knockout to update its observables. Make sure to load jQuery *before* knockout).

Comment: Sadly, that doesn't work. 
Did this to every `val()`: `$(kvkfactory.ctlModelId).val(company.ModelId).change();`

I also added the knockout typing for good measure.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you with any specific pointers, other than a generic "Don't mix jQuery and knockout like you did". If you create a runnable [mimimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I can help debug it...